# Browser and Node.js compatible code require

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-browser

### The Reason

The reason I designed this code was that in many cases, when I wanted to test code in the browser that would be running on a Node instance, the code that I was copying (Don't worry, copying my own code) was huge, around 2 thousand lines. The solution was to move parts of it that were identical across multiple clients (Actually, processes, or characters).

### The Code

The code itself exposes a single function, and a map. The function checks to see which platform you are on (Node, or Browser) and does the respective means to acquire the code for the module you are requesting. Currently, the base path for browser is set to "https://example.com". Feel free to change it to test. Do note, that for it to work in node, a `parent` variable has to be defined, and can be set directly to `global`

I chose to make it async, because it forces the user to realize they are not using a normal require, and doesn't freeze the browser while fetching the code.

#### The Map

The map is designed so that the code can require the same module multiple times without having to fetch the code multiple times. It defines a map, then sets a property upon module request with the name, and the value is the code.

#### What's this thing, game_log?

game_log was an environment specific function that could log things with colors.

```js
// Context: parent is a global variable, essentially just `global`
const proxied_require = (function(root) {
    // Caches modules, persistent across code loads.
    parent.cached_modules = parent.cached_modules || new Map();

    // Copy from parent to a local variable.
    const cached_modules = parent.cached_modules;

    // Please please please be careful loading modules. If you load them from external sources, you may be at risk. Since there is no sandboxing here, all of the browser is available, making this practically a giant XXS potential.
    function proxied_require(library, callback) {

        // Define things that are consistent across implementations
        const arg_names = ["module", "exports", "require"],
              _module = {},
              _exports = _module.exports = {},
              path = "./LIB/" + library;
        game_log(`Checking cache for library: ${library}`, "info");

        // Is the library in the cache?
        if(cached_modules.has(library)) {
            game_log(`Cache hit! Library loaded: ${library}`, "green")
            const code =  cached_modules.get(library);
            Function(...arg_names, code)(_module, _exports, proxied_require);
            callback(_module.exports);
            return;
        }
        game_log(`Cache miss! Loading library: ${library}`, "red");

        // Rudimentary check to see if we are using node.
        if (typeof module != "undefined") {
            game_log("Node.js environment detected, using FS", "lightblue");
            require('fs').readFile(path, (_, code) => {
                game_log(`Library loaded: ${library}`, "lightgreen");

                // A bit hacky.... we wrap the code similar to how node.js does, but we also give it a copy of local variables. This enables it to access the character variable, and other things.
                Function(...arg_names, code)(_module, _exports, proxied_require);

                // Cache the module.
                cached_modules.set(library, code);

                // Call the callback with the results.
                callback(_module.exports);
            });
        } else {
            game_log("Broswer environment detected, using XMLHTTPRequest", "lightblue");
            const oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.open("GET", root + path, true);
            oReq.send()
            oReq.addEventListener("load", () => {
                const code = oReq.responseText;
                game_log(`Library loaded: ${library}`, "lightgreen");
                Function(...arg_names, code)(_module, _exports, proxied_require);
                cached_modules.set(library, code);
                callback(_module.exports);
            });
        }
    }
    return proxied_require;
})("https://example.com");
```

Feel free to adjust any magic strings to test it out.